# Sharepoint Survey attachment

Tags: 2007, survey-list

I have one problem that i am unable to add attachements to sharepoint survey in 2007.

Can any one help on me this?

Shiva...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom list to achieve that, unless you needed the branching logic of the survey list.  As Kelly said, I'm unaware of any 3rd party tools to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SharePoint 2007 surveys do not allow users to add attachments. I am also personally unaware of any third party add-ons that allow for attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to add attachments to Sharepoint Survey.But It is not diaplayin in the survey details.The following code will work for attaching the file

//Survey List
SPList oList = oWeb.List[Guid];
oList.RootFolder.Add(filename,Url,..);

I can browse the file by using Url of the file.But the file is not showing in the survey list page.